# allocating memory per thread in a parallel_for loop

Tags: c++, concurrency, malloc, parallel-processing, parallel.for

I originally have a single-threaded loop which iterates over all pixels of an image and may do various operation with the data.

The library I am using dictates that retrieving pixels from an image must be done one line at a time. To this end I `malloc` a block of memory which can host one row of pixels (`BMM_Color_fl` is a struct containing one pixel's RGBA data as four float values, and `GetLinearPixels()` copies one row of pixels from a bitmap into a `BMM_Color_fl` array.)

```
BMM_Color_fl* line = (BMM_Color_fl*)malloc(width * sizeof(BMM_Color_fl));
for (int y = 0; y < height, y++)
{   
    bmp->GetLinearPixels(0, y, width, line); //Copy data of row Y from bitmap into line.
    BMM_Color_fl* pixel = line; //Get first pixel of line.
    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++, pixel++) // For each pixel in the row...
    {
        //Do stuff with a pixel.
    }
}
free(line);
```

So far so good!

For the sake of reducing execution time of this loop, I have written a concurrent version using `parallel_for`, which looks like this:

```
parallel_for(0, height, [&](int y)
{   
    BMM_Color_fl* line = (BMM_Color_fl*)malloc(width * sizeof(BMM_Color_fl));
    bmp->GetLinearPixels(0, y, width, line);
    BMM_Color_fl* pixel = line;
    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++, pixel++)
    {
        //Do stuff with a pixel.
    }
    free(line);
});
```

While the multithreaded loop is already faster than the original, I realize it is impossible for all threads to use the same memory block, so currently I am allocating and freeing the memory at each loop iteration, which is obviously wasteful as there will never be more threads than loop iterations.

**My question is if and how can I have each thread `malloc` exactly one line buffer and use it repeatedly (and ideally, free it at the end)?**

- As a disclaimer I must state I am a novice C++ user.

**Implementation of suggested solutions:**

```
Concurrency::combinable<std::vector<BMM_Color_fl>> line;

parallel_for(0, height, [&] (int y)
{
    std::vector<BMM_Color_fl> lineL = line.local();
    if (lineL.capacity() < width) lineL.reserve(width);

    bmp->GetLinearPixels(0, y, width, &lineL[0]);

    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
    {
         BMM_Color_fl* pixel = &lineL[x];
         //Do stuff with a pixel.
    }       
});
```

As suggested, I canned the `malloc` and replaced it with a `vector`+`reserve`.

Comment: Sorry but I can’t *not* complain: `malloc` has no place whatsoever in C++ code. Under no circumstance ever, unless you are in fact implementing a custom allocator in terms of `malloc` (but why you would ever do that is beyond me since the default allocator does that already).

Comment: @Konrad I'm not arguing, but could you please explain why?

Comment: Because C++ specifically encapsulates the `malloc` / `free` mechanism in two different ways: (1) via `new`/`delete`, and (2) via allocators. Both offer a superior interface due to strong typing. This improves readability and avoids type errors. Furthermore, even those methods should generally (read: almost *always*) be avoided in favour of managed memory (in your case, a `std::vector` but more generally smart pointers) in order to avoid memory leaks and to simplify the code (no explicit clean-up needed).

Comment: @Konrad As 3 out of the 4 methods you mentioned are unknown to me, I see I have some reading to do. My logic for not using `new/delete` was that the values would be initialized and I was trying to avoid that overhead as I'm overwriting them anyways. Is this logic mistaken?

Comment: You are indeed correct. In this case, an [allocator](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/memory/allocator/) might help. But using a `std::vector` in conjunction with `reserve` is much less hassle and also doesn’t initialise the values.

Comment: @Konrad Thanks, I will definitely look into that, though as far as I can tell it still doesn't go towards solving the concurrency problem, right? Even when I use a `new` array and try to capture it inside the lambda by value (`[=]`) it doesn't work.

Comment: What platform?  Windows?  Linux?  Whose implementation of parallel_for?  Since the curly braces imply scope, can you not use a smart pointer class and let the smart pointer worry about deleting the memory?

Comment: @JimR - (1) Windows (2) Not sure what you mean, concurrency:parallel_for (3) I'm not familiar with smart pointers but I'll be sure to read up on it, thanks.

Comment: @Konrad Thanks for all the advice, I've refactored it to use `std::vector` instead of `malloc`, added revised code in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Concurrency::combinable` class to achieve this.
I am lazy to post the code, but I am sure it is possible.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. If I understand you correctly, I should be creating a `combinable<BMM_Color_fl*>` object of `width` length and calling it's `.local()` inside the loop? And if so, would that be creating a copy of the array per thread or per loop iteration?

Comment: nevermind, figured it out. Added solution code at the end of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having each thread call parallel_for() have them call another function which allocates the memory, calls parallel_for(), and then frees the memory.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I am not manually starting any threads, I am calling parallel_for from my main thread, which automatically splits the loop iterations into separate threads.

Comment: Yes but as you said, you are doing the alloction inside the for loop. You want to put the malloc/free outside the for loop. You can do this by creating another function which mallocs, calls parallel_for() and the frees the memory. Then call this for each thread.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still not following. You're suggesting I create a bunch of new threads and have each of them call allocation/parallel_for/free? Wouldn't that cause each thread to spawn more threads inside the parallel_for? And wouldn't that still not work because each parallel_for would be wrongly using a single memory block for all threads?

Comment: What I mean is - you can do this by creating another function which mallocs, calls an equivalent of parallel_for() and the frees the memory. Then call this for each thread, ie. do your own thread management rather than use parallel_for directly.

Comment: So basically your original for loop in a wrapper.

Comment: Ah I understand what you mean now. Yes, that is definitely the 'plan b' in this scenario but I was hoping there was a way to capture a copy of the array/memory block inside the lambda, and have parallel_for do the managing, as it does automatic load balancing.